# Homogenous system with infinitely many solutions

Tags: linear-algebra

I came across this example, and I was wondering why $n-r \gt 2$, because we have $r \le 3$ and $n=5$.

Here is the example:

> Consider a homogenous system of $3$ equations and $5$ unknowns.
>
> The rank of such a system is at most 3.
>
> Thus $n-r$, which equals $5-r$, is at most $2$.
>
> Since $n-r \gt 2$, it follows that $n \gt r$.
>
> Hence, such a system has infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score 0):

We're given a homogenous system of $3$ equations and $5$ unknowns.

Therefore, the corresponding matrix has order $(3\times 5).$ Do you get this?

Hence,  the rank of the matrix, $r \leq 3$.

Then by the rank nullity theorem/the Dimension theorem,

rank +nulity=5.

$r + n = 5\\
n= 5-r \geq 2$

Recall, that nullity, n = number of free variables = the dimension of nullspace. Since you have at least two free variables, numbers solutions must be infinite.

I hope this helps.